# In-place object construction in a std::queue<std::tuple<XXX, std::variant>>>

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, variant

I've got C++17 code with a `std::queue` containing `std::tuple`s composed of a pointer and a `std::variant`. The code is as follow :

```
struct EventA
{
    int a;
    float b;
    bool c;
};

struct EventB
{
    char x;
    unsigned int y;
};

class Window;
std::queue<std::tuple<Window *, std::variant<EventA, EventB>>> eventQueue;
```

What's the correct syntax to emplace a new element in the queue with constructing the `std::variant` in-place ? I've tried a lot of syntaxes without success :

```
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, -1024, 2.0f, true);
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, 'a', 2048u);
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, {-1024, 2.0f, true});
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, {'a', 2048u});
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, {std::in_place_type<EventA>, -1024, 2.0f, true});
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, {std::in_place_type<EventB>, 'a', 2048u});
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, std::foward_as_tuple(std::in_place_type<EventA>, -1024, 2.0f, true));
eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, std::foward_as_tuple(std::in_place_type<EventB>, 'a', 2048u));
```

Comment: If you want deduction to keep things succinct, you'll need `push` instead of `emplace` ([demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bzB03WV2sJV9RSTq)). And what's wrong with `eventQueue.emplace(nullptr, EventA{-1024, 2.0f, true});` anyway?

Comment: If you can add constructors to Event classes, as replace `tuple` by `pair`, then you can use `eventQueue.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(nullptr), std::forward_as_tuple(std::in_place_type<EventB>, 'a', 2048u));` ([demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VBww1aSQnvZ7qrAT))

Comment: @ildjarn My goal was to avoid temporary obect construction, move construction in the queue, and deletion of the temporary. I would like to directly construct the object inplace in the queue.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I think I will go with your solution, even if I don't like writing trivial constructors of all events classes and would have preferred to use uniform initialization if possible.

Comment: @JayDee : You have this tagged `c++1z`, which guarantees copy-elision. If it's the semantics you're worried about (not the syntax) then, done.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes but in this case, it seems that copy-elision is not applied, see [demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HXDEc1E4uWkNXcSO)